# Find the distribution of $\frac{2(Z_1+Z_2)^2}{(Z_3-Z_4)^2+(Z_5-Z_6)^2}$.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1, X_2$ are iid $N(1,1)$. Suppose $Z_1,\dots, Z_6$ are iid $N(0,1)$. In addition, assume $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent of $Z_1$, $i=1,\dots,6$.  Find the distribution of $$\frac{2(Z_1+Z_2)^2}{(Z_3-Z_4)^2+(Z_5-Z_6)^2}.$$

I know that the sum of normal distributions is also normal but what has me confused is what to do with the division.

Comment: Where are the $X_i$s?

Comment: Is $Z_1$ a $N(0,1)$ or a $N(1,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $Z_i + Z_j$ and $Z_i - Z_j$ for $i\neq j$ are $N(0,2)$, thus
$$
(Z_i \pm Z_j)^2/2 \sim \chi^2(1).
$$
Finally, recall that  $(Z_3 - Z_4)^2+(Z_5 - Z_6)^2 \sim \chi^2(2)$, and if $W \sim \chi^2(n)$ and $V \sim \chi^2(m)$ are independent r.vs, then 
$$
\frac{W/n}{V/m} \sim F(n, m) ,
$$ 
where in your case
$$
\frac{\chi^2(1)/1}{\chi^2(2)/2} \sim F(1,2).
$$

Comment: But what happens if yo have a sum of chisquares?

Comment: See edited answer.